# Using a field atrribute in mysql parameter function cast

Tags: mysql

I want to use a variable (or an attribute of the table) as CAST parameter (AS), I cant find the proper syntax online.
The proof of concept looks like this:

```
SELECT  
          prd_template_field_type,
          @type := prd_template_field_type,
          Min(CAST(prd_template_field_rule_value AS @type)) AS Min, 
          Max(CAST(prd_template_field_rule_value AS @type)) AS Max 
          FROM tbl_prd_template_field
```

Please dont downvote, I really try to give my best to formulate this as clear as possible + long research has been done.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you can cast using a variable, it probably has to be an actual type (keyword).  But besides that, MySQL makes no guarantee as to the order in which a select statement will execute.  The assignment to `@type` could happen _after_ you plan on using that type.

Comment: I tryed this but it also doesnt work:
Min(CAST(prd_template_field_rule_value AS if(prd_template_field_type="double", SIGNED, if(prd_template_field_type="varchar", CHAR, if(prd_template_field_type="int", SIGNED, CHAR))) )) AS Min